# validate_unique causes RelatedObjectDoesNotExist when calling form.is_valid()

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a Problem that i just cant understand.

Assume we have the following 2 Models:

```
from django.db import models

class OtherModel(models.Model):
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    other_obj = models.ForeignKey(OtherModel)
    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

and a simple ModelForm based on MyModel:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

class MyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['name', 'other_obj']
```

which is tested by a simple pytest method:

```
def test_myform():
    form = MyForm(data={})
    assert form.is_valid() is False
```

This works totally fine (test wont fail), until i add a `validate_unique` method to `MyModel`:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
# ...

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # ...

    def validate_unique(self, exclude=None):
        super(MyModel, self).validate_unique(exclude=exclude)

        qs = MyModel.objects.filter(other_obj=self.other_obj)

        if qs.exists() and qs[0].pk != self.pk:
            e = qs[0]
            raise ValidationError('This OtherModel ({}) was already used already exists'.format(e.other))
```

Which gives me the following Error Message (`RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: MyModel has no other_obj`):

```
F
myapp/tests/test_forms.py:66 (test_myform)
def test_myform():
        form = MyForm(data={})
>       assert form.is_valid() is False

test_forms.py:69: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
../../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py:183: in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
../../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py:175: in errors
    self.full_clean()
../../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py:386: in full_clean
    self._post_clean()
../../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py:402: in _post_clean
    self.validate_unique()
../../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py:411: in validate_unique
    self.instance.validate_unique(exclude=exclude)
test_forms.py:35: in validate_unique
    qs = MyModel.objects.filter(other_obj=self.other_obj)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.ForwardManyToOneDescriptor object at 0x7f01b905de10>
instance = <MyModel: MyModel object>
cls = <class 'myapp.tests.test_forms.MyModel'>

    def __get__(self, instance, cls=None):
        """
            Get the related instance through the forward relation.

            With the example above, when getting ``child.parent``:

            - ``self`` is the descriptor managing the ``parent`` attribute
            - ``instance`` is the ``child`` instance
            - ``cls`` is the ``Child`` class (we don't need it)
            """
        if instance is None:
            return self

        # The related instance is loaded from the database and then cached in
        # the attribute defined in self.cache_name. It can also be pre-cached
        # by the reverse accessor (ReverseOneToOneDescriptor).
        try:
            rel_obj = getattr(instance, self.cache_name)
        except AttributeError:
            val = self.field.get_local_related_value(instance)
            if None in val:
                rel_obj = None
            else:
                rel_obj = self.get_object(instance)
                # If this is a one-to-one relation, set the reverse accessor
                # cache on the related object to the current instance to avoid
                # an extra SQL query if it's accessed later on.
                if not self.field.remote_field.multiple:
                    setattr(rel_obj, self.field.remote_field.get_cache_name(), instance)
            setattr(instance, self.cache_name, rel_obj)

        if rel_obj is None and not self.field.null:
            raise self.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist(
>               "%s has no %s." % (self.field.model.__name__, self.field.name)
            )
E           django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: MyModel has no other_obj.

../../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py:194: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist
```

I'm assuming its trying to access a object (OtherModel) that doesnt exist (is None), but shouldn't it be validated in the clean methods?
So i thought writing custom clean methods would solve the problem but either one of the following attempts did **NOT** work:

### Not working attempts

#### adding a `clean` method to `MyModel`:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # ...

    def clean(self):
        if not self.other_obj:
            raise ValidationError("Please set an OtherModel")

    # ...
```

even if you replace `if not self.other_obj` with `if self.other_obj is None` or `if not self.other_obj_id`

#### adding a `clean_other_obj` to `MyModel`:

```
 class MyModel(models.Model):
    # ...

    def clean_other_obj(self):
        if not self.other_obj: # why is this not working
            raise ValidationError("other_obj cant be empty!")
    # ...
```

#### adding a `clean_other_obj` to `MyForm`:

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    # ...

    def clean_other_obj(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['other_obj']
        if not data:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please fill other_obj")
        return data
```

#### adding a `clean` method to `MyForm` and calling `super`:

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    # ...
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(MyForm, self).clean()
        other_obj = cleaned_data.get("other_obj")

        if not other_obj:
            raise forms.ValidationError("other_obj cant be empty")
```

### Working attempts

Oddly either one of these 2 attempts *DID work*:

#### adding a `clean` method to `MyForm` and *WITHOUT* calling `super`:

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    # ...
    def clean(self):
        # cleaned_data = super(MyForm, self).clean()  # This doesnt work!
        other_obj = self.cleaned_data.get("other_obj")

        if not other_obj:
            raise forms.ValidationError("other_obj cant be empty")
```

#### check for `other_obj_id` in `validate_unique` works:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
# ...

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # ...

    def validate_unique(self, exclude=None):
        super(MyModel, self).validate_unique(exclude=exclude)

        if not self.other_obj_id:  # why is this working and not other_obj 
            raise ValidationError("other_obj cant be empty!")

        qs = MyModel.objects.filter(other_obj=self.other_obj)

        if qs.exists() and qs[0].pk != self.pk:
            raise ValidationError('This OtherModel ({}) was already used.'.format(qs[0].other))
```

**Note**: this only works if you check  `other_obj_id`, if you check `other_obj` it STILL wont work

Since these 2 attempts are rather unsatisfying solutions, because in one case the `super` method can't be called and in the other case the `validate_unique` method is missused for cleaning the data instead of only checking for duplicates, I am wondering why this is so and what I am doing wrong.

I know that there have been similar Questions on stackoverflow but none of them give an working answer.

Answers are much appreciated!

Code with all non working attempts: https://pastebin.com/y10ma8EL

Comment: Well a *new* object, has at that moment *no* `other_obj`, hence that will indeed fail. A form builds the `instance` later in the process.

Comment: You shouldn't usually have to override `validate_unique`. For your example, you can do `other_obj = models.ForeignKey(OtherModel, unique=True)` and Django will validate the unique constraint for you. Note that a `OneToOneField` may be a better choice than a foreign key with `unique=True`.

Comment: If you really want to override `validate_unique`, then your version with `if not self.other_obj_id:` looks OK to me. Instead of raising a `ValidationError`, I would return from the function early. The usual validation will raise an error for the empty `other_obj` value.

Comment: Thanks for responding,
other_obj = models.ForeignKey(OtherModel, unique=True) does not work if you have multiple foreignkeys where you want to check that the combination is unique. In case you want to suggest unique_together, this i cant use either because it doesnt work if one of the values is None.

Comment: In that case you can check `self.other_obj_id` and return earlier as I suggested in my other comment.

Comment: Alright, then I will go with that. I appreciate you taking the time, thanks a lot!